# Как сделать нижнюю панель с вкладками?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, не подскажите, как сделать подобную нижнюю панель в android приложении? Хотелось, чтобы она была такой же независимой, как action bar, то есть, при перелистывании фрагмента сохраняла своё положение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это `TabHost` `TabWidget`. Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://gist.github.com/jerolimov/618086)